# When i Enter username and password i get this error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[This is the Error that Iam Talking Could Any Please Help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0itNO.png)

Comment: have you told the password someone around here before?

Comment: check your database credentials

Comment: I have changed the database password in dbconn.php file still it gives the error

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not pictures,

Comment: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Banking\_inc\dbconn.php on line 11
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'bank_db'

Comment: This is the Error Iam getting

Answer (score -1):

It means you have entered the wrong password for your database.

Comment: [I have changed the database password in dbconn.php file still it gives the error]

Comment: Did you flush permissions after changing the password? *EDIT* Sorry, privileges, not permissions. Flush privileges.

Comment: How can I flush permissions?

Comment: just use:
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Banking_inc\dbconn.php on line 11 Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'bank_db

Comment: This is the Error

Comment: Are you sure you have the right user name? That all still looks like just an authentication problem. I'm not sure how to solve it without looking at your machine myself.